# LCD 4 bits mode

Tags: pic, microchip, lcd

I have read in this website: http://www.engineersgarage.com/embedded/avr-microcontroller-projects/interface-lcd-4bit-mode-circuit that when I need to send a command in 4 bits I have first to send a function set command which states 4 bits mode 2 lines and 5x7 font which is 0x28 but we cant send this using 4 bits mode because the lower nibble wont be read so instead I think we should use 0x20 then 0x80 but this website says that I need to make 0x02 while that time the 2 will be in the lower nibble which wont be sent so how can that happen? I have been wondering for so long on how can this happen and I would very much appreciate anyone who can spend a bit of his time to explain this to me and I would be very thankful.

Comment: Are your comma, dot and Enter keys broken? The question is a wall of illegible text...

Comment: sorry @TheParamagneticCroissant what did I do wrong?

Comment: @userXXX You haven't separated phrases and clauses into different sentences and paragraphs. You should format your question nicely so that it's easy to read.

Comment: do u know the answer of my question @TheParamagneticCroissant?

Comment: I don't really know what u mean by format it nicely it just cant be formatted I have no steps to number or code to add and it is a small part for anyone to read if u have any ideas what do I need to do to format it I would be very happy to hear it...

Comment: Paramagnetic isn't looking for lists, but sentences. There are a few questions about this on [ee.se], but the few I looked at didn't really describe it if you don't know where to start. Here is a complete datasheet of the [driver your chip emulates](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf). See page 46 for 4-bit initialization. Basically, you pretend you are sending 8 bits for the first command and the low 4 bits are random, but the high 4 bits say to enter 4 bit mode. Then you can send another initialization command from 4 bit mode to set the other bits.

Comment: I actually know where to start @ughoavgfhw but I need to know why did he put a 0x02 which will not be read because there is a 0 on the higher nibble and the lower nibble is not read instead of 0x20 which is the right one because the 2 is the one which is gonna be read and there is 0 on the lower nibble???

Comment: Oh, I see. Answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for `dis_cmd`, you will see that it first sends the high nibble, then the low nibble. There is no way to make it send only one. Let's look at the two possibilities:

`dis_cmd(0x20)`: Writes 0x2 then 0x0
`dis_cmd(0x02)`: Writes 0x0 then 0x2

As you can see, there will always be an extra 0 sent. If the value 0x20 were used, this would be sent after the mode was changed, causing it to be interpreted as the high nibble of a command, which makes any future command wrong. By sending 0x2, the extra 0 is sent first. It is interpreted as an 8 bit command with the high nibble clear, followed by a command to enter 4 bit mode. Sending a random command on startup is not ideal, but it does work without corrupting future commands.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks very much ughoavgfhw this was the question that confused me for a long while u helped me alot